# How to implement Google Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I just want to say that I am not a web developer.

I work at a high school and we have a Day 1 - 4 schedule rotation. I'm trying to create some sort of calendar that staff and students can subscribe (not sure if this is the correct word) to so that they can schedule information to existing calendars on their smartphones. Similar to how there are calendars for holidays and stuff like that. Google Calendar API allows you to create projects based on a variety of languages. Would I need to create an Android and iOS app to accomplish this or is there some sort of cross-platform scripting that I can use to implement this?

Sorry if what I'm asking seems weird, I'm very new to this API, but I have done some scripting for Google sheets and other Google products and this seems very different. I'm trying to phrase this question so that it's not opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events), you need to call the [`events.insert()`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) method to create an event providing at least these [parameters](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#parameters):

- calendarId
- event

But in order to successfully create events, you need to set your OAuth scope to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` and ensures the authenticated user has write access to the calendar with the `calendarId` you provided (for example by calling [`calendarList.get()`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/get) for the `calendarId` and checking the `accessRole`).

Check the [examples](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) in the documentation.